# multiple users are connected to the same vonage session, and we are in need of a solution to trace and identify these users

Tags: vonage

A issue we are facing with our Vonage sessions. We have observed that multiple users are connected to the same session, and we are in need of a solution to trace and identify these users, as well as determine when a user disconnects from the session.

To provide you with a clearer understanding of problem:

```
User Identification: We require a method to trace and identify all users who are connected to a specific Vonage session simultaneously. This will help us monitor and manage user participation more efficiently.

User Disconnection: It is crucial for us to be able to track when a user disconnects from a session.
```

I tried to get the user list which connected to the same session unable to get it.